# Invalid property 'datasource' of bean class in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"></property>
    <property name="username" value="SYSTEM"></property>
    <property name="password" value="admin"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="datasource" ref="datasource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
    <value>spring.SpringORM.Student</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">   
    <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.oracl11gDialect</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory"  ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="studnetDaoImplement" class="spring.SpringORM.StudnetDaoImplement">
    <constructor-arg ref="hibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>

        </beans>
```

I am getting this error

```
NFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3b0def13: defining beans [datasource,sessionFactory,hibernateTemplate,transactionManager,studnetDaoImplement]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Application-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'datasource' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'datasource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'dataSource'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at spring.SpringORM.StudentTesting.main(StudentTesting.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'datasource' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'datasource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'dataSource'?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: suppose you use replace `datasource` with `dataSource` following the bean naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'datasource' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'datasource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'dataSource'? at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1012) at org.springfr
```

The stack trace is telling you enough. I have the same problems and solved it by renaming "datasource" to "dataSource". That thing is case sensitive so be careful. Hope that helps.